# Prevent Workbench from inserting table columns automatically

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm creating an EER diagram. When I edit a table and add columns to it, I almost always have to remove a bogus column that the program inserts automatically.

E.g., I have table `foo` with a single column `foo_id` and I add `foo_name` I end up with a bogus `foocol` at the end:

[image: foocol]

- Is it possible to disable this feature?
- Is there at least a keyboard short-cut to remove the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press escape and it will remove the column.

Comment: Oh... I tried everything except that! Thank you very much.

Comment: In practice, though, there're times when I've already focused some other row thus *Esc* is no longer an option. *I hate how much Workbench feels alpha after so many years.*